# whether it is good to use Icriteria for joining more tables or should i use inner join using Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

Whether it is good to use Icriteria for joining more than tables rather than using select query in nhibernate.Please give a good link for me to learn asp combined with nhibernate using Icriteria .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some useful information [here](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries#).
It's just a starting point, though.
I would suggest to have a look at [QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) which allows you to use Extension Methods and Lambda.

Comment: @Philipose: no problem. I hope I have helped in some way.